# Microsoft Office 365 SMTP sending limits

Tags: smtp, microsoft-office-365

Company I work for have Office 365 subscription, which as I understand [has 10k emails sent per day limit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#receiving-and-sending-limits) regardless of tier. 
My question is - if I have two separate SMTP logins (e.g. test-login@company-name.com and production-login@company-name.com), does each of them have separate quota or it's 10k per account (which includes both logins)? Its unclear from the docs

Comment: The limit is per-mailbox.

Comment: @GregAskew you mean if I have 2 logins, I can send 20k emails per day?

Comment: Correct. It isn't per identity logon or per email address.